# Handling incorrect SQL Server Log-On Password from Access VBA

Tags: ms-access

I'm using a Switchboard Database to run macros on multiple Access databases one after the other using the code below.  Running the "Updata Data" macro in Data1.accdb requires logging on to a SQL Server.  If a user enters an incorrect password the code freezes.  Any suggestions for how to gracefully handle an incorrect log-on attempt?

```
Set objACC = GetObject("\Data Tables\Data1.accdb") 
objACC.DoCmd.RunMacro ("Update Data") 'run macro
objACC.Quit
```

> Edit: It looks like the problem is not
>   an incorrect login.  I know the macro
>   works when fired from the
>   "Data1.accdb" database but when I kill
>   it on a freeze up there is a message
>   about "not being able to create an
>   Active X component".  I'll do more
>   research and ask a more coherent
>   question when I have more info.  In
>   the mean time I will call the "Use
>   Error Handling" answer correct because
>   that does let me know when the
>   password is incorrect.

Comment: Why not convert the macros to VBA code, and then you can put proper error handling in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
On Error GoTo Error_LogonError

    Dim db_path As String
    db_path = "\Data Tables\Data1.accdb"
    Set objACC = GetObject(db_path) 
    objACC.DoCmd.RunMacro ("Update Data") ''#run macro
    objACC.Quit

Error_LogonError:
    Debug.Print "hi, there was an error logging on to " & db_path
```